# Connection refused when connecting to RabbitMQ via IP address instead of localhost

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm trying to set up a RabbitMQ server (version 3.7.4, installed via homebrew on macOS 10.13.4) such that my colleagues can work with it via the internal network. We are using the official Java client (`com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:5.2.0`). Unfortunately, they only get a `ConnectException` with the message `Connection refused`:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:62)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:134)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:997)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:956)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:914)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1068)
    at my.own.private.RabbitMqConnector.connect(RabbitMqConnector.java:29)
```

We already set up another user account (not `guest`) which has admin privileges. With almost the same Java code I can connect locally (setting the host to `localhost`) but not if I use my IP address. According to the RabbitMQ docs, the RabbitMQ server binds to all network interfaces by default (otherwise I would have said that it's a problem with address binding). I disabled my firewall so that shouldn't be the problem.

Here's the respective code:

```
final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.setUsername("username");
connectionFactory.setPassword("password");
connectionFactory.setHost("10.10.33.12");
connectionFactory.setPort(5672);
connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("/");

try (final Connection connection = connectionFactory.newConnection()) {
    // doo stuff with the connection
}
```

Comment: Smells like a firewall issue.

Comment: Can you check if the user(s) are part of the [loopback_users](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the actual problem and it's not related to Java or how I configured the `ConnectionFactory`. It was indeed a problem how the RabbitMQ package for homebrew is configured. In the `rabbitmq-env.conf` file, there was the following setting

```
NODE_IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
```

This setting caused RabbitMQ to only listen on 127.0.0.1 for incoming connections. Once I removed the setting and restarted the service, I could connect from other machines as well.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with your code. I would suggest you to check such things:

- RabbitMQ Server is up and running
- Your custom user can access virtual host "/"
- Check firewall settings if any, probably it's refusing connection with remote host

One of these should be the cause, hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you but I checked all of that. The server is running, the user can access the virtual host "/" and I disabled the firewall (fyi @theMayer)

Comment: @RobertB, the issue is still persists? Could you post full stack trace?

Comment: yes the issue still persists :( I posted the full stack already.

Comment: The other guys in your team could access it?

Comment: @RobertB try to go through [Troubleshooting Network Connectivity](https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-networking.html) topic.